# Is it possible to do this in SQL (summing rows over different criteria per user)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE diet_watch (
  entry_date date NOT NULL,
  user_id    int default 1,
  weight     double precision NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 1, 128.2);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-02', 1, 121.2);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-03', 1, 100.6);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-04', 1, 303.7);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-05', 1, 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 2, 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-06', 2, 128.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-07', 2, 138.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 3, 128.2);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-02', 3, 125.5);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-03', 3, 112.8);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-06', 3, 111.2);
```

I further have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE summing_period (
    user_id INT NOT NULL, 
    start_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    end_date DATE NOT NULL); 

insert into summing_period VALUES (1, '2001-01-01', '2001-01-03'); 
insert into summing_period VALUES (2, '2001-01-02', '2001-01-06'); 
insert into summing_period VALUES (3, '2001-01-03', '2001-01-06');
```

I want to write a query that returns DISTINCT ROWS with the following columns:

- the **user_id**
- the **sum of the weights** in table `diet_watch` between the specified dates in table summing_period (for the user_id)

So the result of the query based on the data in table summing period should be:

```
1,350.0
2,128.0
3,224.0
```

Unfortunately, this time, I have reached the limit of my SQLfu - and I no idea how to even get started in writing the SQL. Ideally, the solution should be ANSI SQL (i.e. db agnostic). however, since I am developing to a PostgreSQL 8.4 backend, if the solution is db centric, it must at least run on PG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    sp.user_id, SUM(dw.weight)
FROM
    summing_period sp,
    diet_watch dw
WHERE
    dw.user_id = sp.user_id AND
    dw.entry_date >= sp.start_date AND
    dw.entry_date <= sp.end_date
GROUP BY
    sp.user_id
```

What this query does is join each `diet_watch` row to the row in `summing_period` that matches its `user_id` and whose date falls in the `summing_period`'s range.

The `SELECT` then asks for the `SUM` of the weights for each different `user_id` (as a result of the `GROUP BY user_id`).

Comment: I wasn't sure if a join as used here would work with Postgres (I'm not as familiar with it as other flavors of SQL) but I checked on sqlfiddle and this works as well... and is probably a better way than my own answer.  +1

Comment: this works, and you can test other flavors of sql here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/26d0c/5

Comment: Whoa... SQL Fiddle is awesome!  How have I not come across that before!?  (Thanks, RThomas!)

Comment: Awesome - yes - but don't feel bad, it's pretty new.  It was built by @Jake Feasel a few months ago to demonstrate sql based answers here on S.O.  Making Jake Feasel a royal knight of the S.O. round-table in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, it looks so simple. I almost feel foolish for having asked the question. Thanks though - SQL has always been my achilles heel.